# Why toUri().toURL() loads local path on begining?

Tags: java, classloader

I have part of code which loads the classes from files and then create the instances of them. For now I have unit tested them with my local project and everything seems to work properly.

After all, I wanted to wire up my part with the camel and from this point the class responsible for loading other classes started to behave in strange way. It seems that toUri().toURL() adds local path before the actuall path which is given as parameter. So in such case I get following values.

```
DIR =       file:D:\WORKSPACES\PROJ1\Parser\target\classes\com\somecompany\someproduct\SpecializedParser\EventReasonSpecializedParserImpl.class
PATH =      file:D:/WORKSPACES/PROJ1/Parser/target/classes/com/somecompany/someproduct/SpecializedParser/
LOADPATH =  file:/D:/WORKSPACES/PROJ1/TestPrograms/ContentBasedRouterTestServer/file:D:/WORKSPACES/PROJ1/Parser/target/classes/com/somecompany/someproduct/SpecializedParser/EventReasonSpecializedParserImpl.class
PACKCLASSNAME = com.somecompany.someproduct.SpecializedParser.EventReasonSpecializedParserImpl
```

And should be

```
PATH =      file:D:/WORKSPACES/PROJ1/Parser/target/classes/com/somecompany/someproduct/SpecializedParser/
LOADPATH =  file:D:/WORKSPACES/PROJ1/Parser/target/classes/com/somecompany/someproduct/SpecializedParser/EventReasonSpecializedParserImpl.class
PACKCLASSNAME = com.somecompany.someproduct.SpecializedParser.EventReasonSpecializedParserImpl
```

Check the difference in loadpath. The code behind is:

```
public class ClassLoaderHelper {
  static HashMap<String, Class> classKeeper = new HashMap<>();
  public static Class getClasFromPath(String path, String className, String packageName) throws ParserException {
   String packPlusClassName = packageName + className;

   if (classKeeper.containsKey(packPlusClassName)) {
     return classKeeper.get(packPlusClassName);
   }

   File dir = new File(path + className + ".class");
   URL loadPath = null;
   try {
     loadPath = dir.toURI().toURL();
   } catch (MalformedURLException mue) {
     throw new ParserException("Malformed URL Exception - " + mue.getMessage());
   }
   URL[] classUrl = new URL[]{loadPath};
   ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(classUrl);
   System.out.println("DIR = " + dir);
   System.out.println("PATH = " + path);
   System.out.println("LOADPATH = " + loadPath);
   System.out.println("PACKCLASSNAME = " + packPlusClassName);

   Class returnClass = null;
   try {
     returnClass = cl.loadClass(packPlusClassName);
   } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
     throw new ParserException("Parser class not found: " + className + " in package " + packageName);
   }
   classKeeper.put(packPlusClassName, returnClass);
   return returnClass;
 }
```

}

Why, when it is called from camel, it puts local path on the beggining of loadpath? How to avoid such sitatuion - I don't even know where to start, because toURI().toURL() should just return what I'm intrested in - nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: 1) Why are you giving path starting with "file:" to the `Dir` constructor? Why not just local path? 2) Why you don't put a "/" after "file:"?

Comment: I think the simpliest answer will be that the unit tests passed. And when everything passed I didn't care :/ TDD weakness.

Comment: OK, I removed file: from dir initialization. The loadpath seems better, but still something is missing. The question is also - why does it earlier work?

Answer (score 0):

Finaly I was not able to use the `URLClassLoader` so I tried another approaches and as a result I get:

```
public class ClassLoaderHelper extends ClassLoader {

  public ClassLoaderHelper(ClassLoader parent) {
    super(parent);
  }

static HashMap<String, Class> classKeeper = new HashMap<>();

public Class getClasFromPath(String path, String className, String packageName) throws MalformedURLException, URISyntaxException, IOException {
  String packPlusClassName = packageName + className;

  if (classKeeper.containsKey(packPlusClassName)) {
    return classKeeper.get(packPlusClassName);
  }

  URL newUrl = new URL("file:" + path + className + ".class").toURI().toURL();

  URLConnection connection = newUrl.openConnection();
  ByteArrayOutputStream buffer;
  try (InputStream input = connection.getInputStream()) {
    buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int data = input.read();
    while (data != -1) {
      buffer.write(data);
      data = input.read();
    }
  }

  byte[] classData = buffer.toByteArray();
  Class returnClass = defineClass(null, classData, 0, classData.length);
  classKeeper.put(packPlusClassName, returnClass);
  return returnClass;
  }
}
```

Where the path has following shape:

`String path = "D:\\WORKSPACES\\product\\component\\target\\classes\\com\\company\\product\\ContextSpecializedParser\\";`

Additionally I was not able to instance loaded class so I use invoking methods mechasnim as follow:

```
ClassLoaderHelper clh = new ClassLoaderHelper(componentClass.class.getClassLoader());

specParser = clh.getClasFromPath(path, parser.ClassName, packageName).newInstance();
    Class[] cArg = new Class[2];
    cArg[0] = Object.class;
    cArg[1] = String.class;

    method = specParser.getClass().getMethod("Method", cArg);
```